# Python inclusive executable

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller, py2exe

I am struggling with creating .exe or similar formatted files with my python 3.6 project. I have success with creating an exe using pyinstaller, but it requires me to have installed the module pymysql separately and to include the icon.ico file in the same directory as the new application.

How would I go about creating a standalone executable that not only stores the icon.ico used for the program title icon, and including the pymysql module as well as seperate .py files?
I've tried using different arguments within pyinstaller, and I've looked at py2exe but this doesn't seem to support python 3.6.

Comment: What exact pyinstaller commands have you tried?

Comment: @rnso I've tried using the -F to create it as a standalone, and then read that you can add commands like the --icon thing, (Never used a python compiler to create executables before and am only learning python while at university). However, I couldn't find much information on python 3.6 and most things suggest backdating versions which I can't do as I'm required to use 3.6